# oracle 10g foreign key constraints

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

```
ALTER TABLE  employees
ADD  CONSTRAINT emp_dno_fk FORIEGN KEY(Dno) REFERENCES Departments(Dno);
```

When I use this command it shows an error like

> CONSTRAINT Specification not allowed here.

But when I use this command it works:

```
ALTER TABLE  employees
ADD  CONSTRAINT emp_dno_fk Dno REFERENCES Departments(Dno);
```

Can anyone tell me why Oracle doesn't allow FOREIGN KEY KEYWORD in the first command?

Comment: i before e, except after c, except for neighbor and foreign.  :)

Comment: At school, we were taught "i" before "e" when the sound is "eee", which excludes neighbour, foreign (and reign) which are more like an "ay" sound, and science which is "si-en".

Comment: @Gary: In my young day, we were forced to memorize the spelling of each and every word. That was the way we were taught, and we LIKED it! :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message, admittedly, is not very helpful. The following are examples of how a referential integrity constraint may be created in Oracle:

The following examples assume that the column `Dno` already exists in `employees`:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD
  CONSTRAINT emp_dno_fk FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES Departments (Dno);

ALTER TABLE employees ADD
  FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES Departments (Dno);
```

The following examples assume that the column `Dno` does not already exist in `employees`:

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD
  CONSTRAINT emp_dno_fk Dno REFERENCES Departments (Dno);

ALTER TABLE employees ADD
  Dno REFERENCES Departments (Dno);
```

Personally, I avoid the syntax versions which add the column and prefer to add it myself.

Comment: I didnt understood what are you trying to say. plz explain me in detail.thanks in advance

Comment: I'm trying to give you examples of valid syntax. Compare these examples with what you're using.